# A value of type 'String' cannot be assigned to a variable of type 'Hero'

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am learning Dart. When I am writing next code:

```
class Hero 
{
    String name;

    Hero(this.name);
}

class AppComponent
{
    String title = 'header';
    Hero hero = 'Windstorm';
}


Hero hero = new Hero('test');
```

I am getting error:
`A value of type 'String' cannot be assigned to a variable of type 'Hero'`.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: As for me, the message `A value of type 'String' cannot be assigned to a variable of type 'Hero'` is explain a lot. Of course, if you know English. Not a very serious question.

Answer (score 8):

The problem seems to be in this line:

```
Hero hero = 'Windstorm';
```

hero is of type Hero.
'Windstorm' is of type String.
So one cannot be assigned to the other just like that.

You can try this:

```
Hero hero = new Hero('Windstorm');
```

Just like you did in your last line with 'test'.

If there is a constructor for the class Hero that takes a string as an argument, then it will work.

Comment: But my code is from https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html error there?

Comment: Maybe somebody else can confirm but I think so. Later on they create a class for the hero and use a constructor. Quote: "Because we changed the hero from a string to an object"... so looks like it used to be a string. (I'm not terribly familiar with Dart :$)

Comment: Thanks for the report! I've asked the authors of that tutorial if that was an intentional bug.

Comment: Nice! All the way to the source :)

Answer (score -1):

Here sample,

```
export class AppComponent  {

 hero = new Hero('windstrom');
}

export class Hero 
{
    name: string;

    constructor(Name: string){
    this.name =Name;
    }
}

let hero = new Hero('test');
```

It's works